# Align and export

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, alignment

I am working on time-lapse taking photos every day at a specific location for the next 30 days.

Although I am doing my best to centre the photos always in the same place, sometimes various photos will need to be aligned.

I will create the final time-lapse with a specific software, however, I still would like to align all the photos first with photoshop.

Is there a way to do the alignment and then export back every single aligned photo?

Comment: And what makes this a graphic design question?

Comment: It does not matter what you do with your images in the end, I believe that the question of how to align and export images should serve even graphic design working with multiple images. Lucian you can do two things: criticizing and ignoring my request for help, or simply help

Comment: Criticizing (including down and close votes) are allowed when a question is offtopic, unclear or broad: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Editing a timelapse is a specific photography technical question and barely related to graphic design. You can also align cars in a parking lot but that's not called graphic design.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? Do you know how to import photos to Photoshop, align and export files? You can probably align manually, 30 photos is not so much.

Comment: You have to do it manually as Luciano said. The program doesn't know what you want it to align.

Comment: I agree this isn't a graphic design questions. But I will say this, that's not how timelapse photography is done.  The camera has to be fixed in position (usually on a tripod), and each shot should be exactly the same, so that there is no need for aligning.  Aligning afterwards automatically would need some software that would be able to identify what is or what isn't supposed to be moving in each shot - and that would need some sort of artificial intelligence - it's certainly not something trivial.

Comment: What if there's an answer to this question, but the consensus appears that this is the wrong location for the question, therefore, the wrong location for the answer? Wait until it's moved to a stack exchange to which I am not subscribed?

Comment: I feel this question fits here just fine. I mean it does involve same methods graphic designers would use. A car mechanic can probably tell me how to use a wrench, even if I don't use it on a car... That said, people at https://photo.stackexchange.com/ might have a better grasp of how this aligning issue should be handled. You may want to delete this post and post it in there instead. Or maybe wait a while for people here to figure out what they want.

Comment: Even if it was ontopic, which it is not, this is still very much unclear and also broad. Some people here may be able to answer this, but the OP is not making the effort to provide enough detail. The issue is clearly very specific, and the OP is either doing the wrong thing or just not explaining enough.

Comment: @Fabrizio Have a look at [StackExchange's Photography group](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an action for this task. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html

It'd simply create the document using "File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack" to fetch the photos as individual layers.

Then, select all layers and "Edit > Auto-Align Layers".

And export all the layers using "File > Export > Layers to Files..."